# Implementing chained iterators in a Ruby C extension

Tags: c, ruby, enumerable

I see that there's a relatively new feature in Ruby which allows chained iteration -- in other words, instead of `each_with_indices { |x,i,j| ... }` you might do `each.with_indices { |x,i,j| ... }`, where `#each` returns an `Enumerator` object, and `Enumerator#with_indices` causes the additional yield parameters to be included.

So, `Enumerator` has its own method `#with_index`, presumably for one-dimensional objects, [source found here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index). But I can't figure out the best way to adapt this to other objects.

**To be clear, and in response to comments:** Ruby doesn't have an `#each_with_indices` right now -- it's only got an `#each_with_index`. (That's why I want to create one.)

A series of questions, themselves chained:

1. How would one adapt chained iteration to a *one*-dimensional object? Simply do an `include Enumerable`?
2. Presumably the above (#1) would not work for an *n*-dimensional object. Would one create an `EnumerableN` class, derived from `Enumerable`, but with `#with_index` converted into `#with_indices`?
3. Can #2 be done for Ruby extensions written in C? For example, I have a matrix class which stores various types of data (floats, doubles, integers, sometimes regular Ruby objects, *etc.*). Enumeration needs to check the data type (`dtype`) first as per the example below.

Example:

```
VALUE nm_dense_each(VALUE nm) {
  volatile VALUE nm = nmatrix; // Not sure this actually does anything.
  DENSE_STORAGE* s = NM_STORAGE_DENSE(nm); // get the storage pointer

  RETURN_ENUMERATOR(nm, 0, 0);

  if (NM_DTYPE(nm) == nm::RUBYOBJ) { // matrix stores VALUEs

    // matrix of Ruby objects -- yield those objects directly
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nm_storage_count_max_elements(s); ++i)
      rb_yield( reinterpret_cast<VALUE*>(s->elements)[i] );

  } else { // matrix stores non-Ruby data (int, float, etc)

    // We're going to copy the matrix element into a Ruby VALUE and then operate on it. This way user can't accidentally
    // modify it and cause a seg fault.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nm_storage_count_max_elements(s); ++i) {
      // rubyobj_from_cval() converts any type of data into a VALUE using macros such as INT2FIX()
      VALUE v = rubyobj_from_cval((char*)(s->elements) + i*DTYPE_SIZES[NM_DTYPE(nm)], NM_DTYPE(nm)).rval;
      rb_yield( v ); // yield to the copy we made
    }
  }
}
```

**So, to combine my three questions into one:** How would I write, in C, a `#with_indices` to chain onto the `NMatrix#each` method above?

I don't particularly want anyone to feel like I'm asking them to code this for me, though if you did want to, we'd love to have you involved in our project. =)

But if you know of some example elsewhere on the web of how this is done, that'd be perfect -- or if you could just explain in words, that'd be lovely too.

Comment: No there isn't such feature. Nothing as you mention exists in Ruby 1.9. And no such thing as you mention was introduced in Ruby 2.0. However, Ruby has a different thing called `each_with_index`. And Ruby 1.9 introduced `with_index`.

Comment: Okay, fixed my question -- it's now general to Ruby. Did you downvote? Might I ask why? It's a pretty carefully written question.

Comment: @sawa: He does not ask about Ruby features. This is a high level question, He is a dev, probably a part of NMatrix team, and he is basically asking what is the Ruby way of writing Ruby methods in C :-) I am (presently) Marc-Andre's Matrix user, and I am happy to have NMatrix arround as an alternative.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky The OP writes `each_with_indices { |x,i,j| ... }`, which I strongly believe that it was intended as a Ruby code. I am mentioning that no such thing exists at least in standard Ruby.

Comment: @sawa: You are completely right. I think that the OP is already all in his imagined NMatrix#each_with_indices method, because 2D matrices have 2 indices :-) Lemme go and [see their repo, how the NMatrix heroes are doing...](https://github.com/sciruby/nmatrix)

Comment: Oh, I know there's no such thing as `each_with_indices`, but there is an `each_with_index`. That a key part of my question -- since I can't just `include Enumerable` in order to get the functionality I need. Two people voted to close. What's up with that?

Comment: @mohawkjohn: Hi there, your nmatrix fails to install on my Debian/Ruby2.0.0. I have followed the instalation instructions and tried to install dependencies with apt-get. Is it supposed to work under Ruby2.0.0?

Comment: Yes. Rumor has it that you need to install ATLAS manually -- that the Debian/Ubuntu package won't cut it. Haven't been able to prove this, but most of the bug reports seem to come from people using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

`#with_index` is a method of `Enumerator`: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index

I suppose you could make a subclass of `Enumerator` that has `#with_indices` and have your `#each` return an instance of that class? That's the first thing that comes to mind, although your enumerator might have to be pretty coupled to the originating class...

Comment: Yes, but I think his problem is that he wants to write it in C. He is on a completely different level than us quiche eaters ;-)

Comment: Sure, but it's nice to understand the principles in Ruby first. I think the problem is that `Enumerator`/`Enumerable` doesn't have `#with_indices`, only `#with_index`. I'm not sure of the appropriate mechanism for creating the former.

Comment: Most (all?) `Enumerable` methods return an `Enumerator` if you don't pass them a block. That's how `foo.map.with_index`, `bar.each.with_object`, etc. work.

Comment: One thought is to create `NEnumerator` which has `#with_indices`, and then create an `NEnumerable` layer which translates `Enumerable` calls to return `NEnumerator`s instead of `Enumerator`s.

Maybe it might be easier to just have `#each` return an object from which you can extract the `value` and `indices` instead.

Comment: @kejadlen: Exactly. Ordinary `Enumerator` / `Enumerable` are specific to 1-dimensional collections. I wonder whether having `NEnumerable` / `NEnumerator` would be an overkill. It seems to me that yes, but I might be mistaken...

Comment: I don't know much about `NMatrix` unfortunately, but if you want to preserve the existing behavior of `each`, you could copy what `String` does and include a method that returns the object I suggested above. `matrix.enum_with_index.map {|obj| obj.indices }` or something?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that you are also interested in Ruby linguistics, not just C, let me contribute my 5 cents, without claiming to actually answer the question. `#each_with_index` and `#with_index` already became so idiomatic, that majority of the people rely on the index being a number. Therefore, if you go and implement your `NMatrix#each_with_index` in such way, that in the block `{ |e, i| ... }` it would supply eg. arrays `[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], ...` as index `i`, you would surprise people. Also, if others chain your `NMatrix#each` enumerator with `#with_index` method, they will receive just a single number as index. So, indeed, you are right to conclude that you need a distinct method to take care for the 2 indices-type (or, more generally, n indices for higher dimension matrices):

```
matrix.each_with_indices { |e, indices| ... }
```

This method should return a 2-dimensional (n-dimensional) array as `indices == [i, j]` . You should not go for the version:

```
matrix.each_with_indices { |e, i, j| ... }
```

As for the `#with_index` method, it is not your concern at all. If your `NMatrix` provides `#each` method (which it certainly does), then `#with_index` will work normally with it, out of your control. And you do not need to ponder about introducing matrix-specific `#with_indices`, because `#each` itself is not really specific to matrices, but to one-dimensional ordered collections of any sort. Finally, sorry for not being a skilled C programmer to cater to your C-related part of the question.

Comment: Really? An Array instead of an *array? Can you provide some justification for that? It's an interesting thought, but I'm not sure I'm convinced yet.

Comment: The justification is, that others will come up with higher-dimensional objects. Such as 3-dimensional matrices (which I should not really call tensors). And there you have expectable behavior regardless of the number of dimensions. And in Ruby, it is really easy to write `i, j = indices`. I suspect that oftenimes the users will not even have to write `i, j = indices` and instead they will be convenienced by having i, j prepackaged and not having to write something like `curr_pos = [i, j]`...

Comment: Current code accounts for higher dimensions. You just do `#each_with_indices { |val, i, j, k, l| ... }` for example.

Comment: Congrats to those dimensions. The ultimate choice is yours. I lack skill to formalize the reasons for my preference. Earlier, I would have preferred `|val, i, j, k, ...|`. With experience in Ruby, I learned that this cheap convenience of passing collection members unpackaged to methods has some downside or two. I just forgot what it was. What I can say, is, that for the target users, NMatrix will do 98% of their computations, but actual NMatrix method calls will constitute just 2% of their code base. So don't sacrifice political correctness for saving 1 line of user code in those calls.